# How can I access environment variables in index.html?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics. I have different tracking codes for each of my environments (dev, prod, etc). I don't have access to `environments.ts` from `index.html` as far as I know.

I tried loading the script from inside Angular, but then I lost tracking of how long the app's initial load took. I also saw that `.angular-cli.json` has a `scripts` section that I could possibly use, but I don't know how I'd switch which script I run based on the environment.

How can I set this up?

Comment: You can't access environment variables there. It's just a static file. Try using something like [Angulartics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2).

Comment: I am. Angulartics tells me to put my GA script tag in index.html and doesn't mention environments in their documentation at all.

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/issues/106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Angular 6 you can configure file replacements in `angular.json`:

```
"configurations": {
  "dev": {
    ...
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/myScripts.js",
        "with": "src/myScripts.dev.js",
      }
    ]
  },
  "production": {
    ...
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/myScripts.js",
        "with": "src/myScripts.prod.js",
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 8 or above version just modify the *production:configuration* section in *angular.json* as below

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "index": "src/index.html"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "index": "src/index.prod.html"
        }
      }
    }
```

Hope this answer helps.

Regards,
Kirti Singh | Soluzione IT Services